# How to fill an array in Swift from another class

Tags: swift, xcode

I need to fill a array with values which is in a class:

```
class a {

     var selectedRows: [Int]?

     init() {}

     init(number: Int) {
            selectedRows?.append(number)
        }
}
```

How can I fill this array from another class?

Comment: can you get that in other class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trying to declare an array of custom objects in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685593/trying-to-declare-an-array-of-custom-objects-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should initialitze the array. The array is not set and therefore it will not add any number.

best practice in my opininion would be:

```
class a {

     var selectedRows: [Int] = []

     init() {}

     init(number: Int) {
            selectedRows.append(number)
        }
}
```

you can also add an append function

```
append(number: Int) {
   selectedRows.append(number)
}
```

or extend the array to add custom functionality as asked here: [How can I extend typed Arrays in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027116/how-can-i-extend-typed-arrays-in-swift)